# Javascript Mustache invalid template on code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I am working on an application and I have install mustache via npm.

Then in my main.js file I imported it like this:

```
const Mustache = require('mustache')
```

I then have a html template file with this:

`<title>{{ title }}</title>` in the tile part of the html file.

Using node I've then loaded the template file and tried to run render.

Here's the code:

```
fs.readFile('template.html', (err, data) => {

  var mydata = Mustache.render(data, {title: "sometitle"});

  fs.writeFile('result.html', mydata, (err) => {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');

  });

});
```

I keep getting this error:

***TypeError: Invalid template! Template should be a "string" but "object" was given as the first argument for mustache#render***

How can I fix this so I can change and save the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here: [node doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) if you do not specify the encoding thena the callback will receive a raw buffer; if you want a string just add an encoding (let's say the file it is in UTF-8):

```
fs.readFile('template.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  var mydata = Mustache.render(data, {title: "sometitle"});
  fs.writeFile('result.html', mydata, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The file has been saved!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after trying your code

Comment: Can you verify the type of "data"?